# The constructor to deserialize an object of type T was not found

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I tried to undertand the ISerializable and stumped on this. I made two classes both with the attribute "Serializable". Only one class is derived from ISerializable and GetObjectData was defined for it. Let us call this class A. Another was not derived from ISerializable there by GetObjectData was not defined for that. Let us call this class as B. I didnt provide any special constructor for  class A. Now in the run time class A is showing the error like "Special constructor is missing". The syntax is same for both the classes. So, the error may be some other thing but it shouldn't be  regarding the constructor. Otherwise I should get the same error for class B too. See the code below. Can anybody say the reason behind it?
**Note:     I am using windows 7 - 64 bit with visual studio 2010.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

namespace Delete_This
{
    [Serializable]
    class After_Implementing_ISerializable:ISerializable
    {
        int a;
        string b;
        public After_Implementing_ISerializable(int a, string b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {

        }
        public void Check()
        {
            After_Implementing_ISerializable s = new After_Implementing_ISerializable(15, "100");
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("temp.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(fs, s);
            fs.Close();

            fs = new FileStream("temp.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            After_Implementing_ISerializable d = (After_Implementing_ISerializable)bf.Deserialize(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class Without_Implementing_ISerializable
    {
        int a;
        string b;
        public Without_Implementing_ISerializable(int a,string b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void Check()
        {
            Without_Implementing_ISerializable s = new Without_Implementing_ISerializable(15, "100");
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("temp.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(fs, s);
            fs.Close();

            fs = new FileStream("temp.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            Without_Implementing_ISerializable d = (Without_Implementing_ISerializable)bf.Deserialize(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Without_Implementing_ISerializable s = new Without_Implementing_ISerializable(5,"Five");
            s.Check();

            After_Implementing_ISerializable s1 = new After_Implementing_ISerializable(6, "Six");
            s1.Check();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I got

```
"The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'Delete_This.After_Implementing_ISerializable' was not found."}
```

Comment: @Raymond thank you for the nice edit to the topic

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a Serialization constructor for types implementing [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); that serialization constructor is responsible for deserializing the object as it did for serialization using `GetObjectData` method.

Serialization constructor will look something like this, with first parameter `SerializationInfo` and second `StreamingContext`.

```
protected ClassName(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{

}
```

Remarks section in the provided link talks about this topic.

> The ISerializable interface implies a constructor with the signature
>   constructor (SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context).
>   At deserialization time, the current constructor is called only after
>   the data in the SerializationInfo has been deserialized by the
>   formatter. In general, this constructor should be protected if the
>   class is not sealed.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to describe one constructor. My question is in both the classes Check() function is having same syntax. See the object d in both places. Then how come the run time shows error for only one. Interface can't implement anything regarding constructor. The error is regarding constructor. This is the point which confuses me.

Comment: @prabhakaran Am I missing something? Your second class is not implementing `ISerializable` interface, so this constructor is not required there. This is mandatory for types which implement  `ISerializable` interface

Comment: @SriramCan you just put some code to explain the first line. I think that point can clear out all the things.–

Comment: @prabhakaran Which point you can't understand? I'll suggest you to read the example in the link which I provided in my answer. Read all the comments in that code. It shows what is serialization constructor with comment `// The special constructor is used to deserialize values. ` If you implement ISerializable, you must add that constructor. Am not clear which part you have doubt, If you can say that I'll explain.

Comment: @SriramThis is my core point. How an interface can induce a constructor related error. Interface has nothing to do with constructor. As for as I know You can't define constructors through interface at any cost. Am I correct?

Comment: @prabhakaran You are absolutely correct. but `ISerializable` is a special interface which needs constructor also. If not provided you'll get an error. Is that clear?

Comment: @SriramOk. You provided the answer for the question I asked. Thank you. But I still have to find how an interface can instanciate a constructor related error.